# Are these images of identifiable pre-Columbian mythic entities?

Tags: myth-identification, native-american

This is the front and back of a t-shirt that was bought in Colombia. Stylistically to my naive layman eyes, they both look consistent with a modern riff on Muisca or Tairona art. Are they identifiable entities in known pre-Columbian mythology? Or are they tourist trap nonsense? (even so, one would think it might have been easier to copy a pre-existing image):

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: The first image is pretty similar to this one: https://journals.openedition.org/nuevomundo/docannexe/image/69281/img-5-small480.jpg

The being has the same two animal tails, the arms are in similar positions, and there's a certain similarity in the headdress.

I extracted this image from an article whose author analyzes the characteristics of animals present in representations of the gods on middle horizon and later pre-hispanic painted funerary textiles from the peruvian coast [1]

I'll put the reference in another comment...

Comment: Reference:
[1] KARADIMAS, Dimitri. Monkeys, Wasps and Gods: graphic perspectives on middle horizon and later pre-hispanic painted funerary textiles from the peruvian coast. Nuevo Mundo Mundos Nuevos, [s.l.], jul. 2016. Available in: https://doi.org/10.4000/nuevomundo.69281.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**These are, conclusively, *Coclé*, but the culture appears to be very similar to Tairona.**

It appears that these images are near-perfect replicas of the imagery on two [Gran Coclé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gran_Cocl%C3%A9) plaques. What appears to be the same entity as the first image is identified [here](http://benedante.blogspot.com/2017/09/gold-of-panama.html) as a "sun deity" and [here](https://www.meisterdrucke.com/kunstdrucke/Pre-Columbian/257248/Embossed-Plaque-mit-einem-Krokodil-Gott,-aus-Sitio-Conte,-Cocle-Provinz,-Panama,-Late-Cocle-Stil-(Gold).html) as a "crocodile god". Cooke and Bray (ref 1) identify this as a "saurian-human figure", and note that Helms (ref 2) makes a strong case that the animals are iguanas. I have unfortunately not been able to find a copy of that paper.

In any case, the two specific images are conclusively from artifacts found at [sitio Conte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitio_Conte), which are currently at Penn Museum: [the saurian-human plaque](https://www.penn.museum/collections/object/133475) and [the bird figures plaque](https://www.penn.museum/collections/object/49262).
[image: saurian plaque]
[image: bird plaque]

In researching this, I was surprised how similar Tairona art was to precolumbian Panamanian artefacts. Compare, for example these Tairona "twins" (photo: WERNER FORMAN/GTRES, from [this National Geographic article](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/history/magazine/2019/11-12/ancient-lost-city-colombia-teyuna/#/01-golden-twins.jpg)):
[image: Tairona twins]

vs these from the other end of Panama (from Cooke, Bray, ibid., p. 38):
[image: Chiriqui twins]

---

**References**:

1. Cooke, Richard G. and Bray, Warwick. "The Goldwork of Panama: an Iconographic and Chronological Perspective." *The Art of Precolumbian Gold*, 1985, p.39.
2. Helms, Mary W. "Iguanas and Crocodilians in Tropical American Mythology and Iconography with special reference to Panama". *Journal of Latin American Lore* 3(1): 51-132, 1977